# How to get the jSON data value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I just want to ask about my problem. I am a beginner in using jquery.
My problem is I want to get the json string from my jquery ajax request but I don't know how. Because I want to check if the json string values are correct.

Here's my code in jquery ajax:

```
$('#search-btn').on('click',function(){

            var query = $("#keyword").val();

            var image = "<?php echo base_url()."/resources/loading/loading43.gif"; ?>";

            $('#loading').html("<img src='"+image+"' class='loeader' align='center' />");

            var query_url = "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/searchItem'); ?>";

            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url: query_url,
                data:{query: $("#keyword").val(), data_filter: $("#keyword").attr("data-selection")},    //how can I get the value of data_filter? and pass it to the controller?
                dataType:'json',
                async: false,
                success:function(d){
                      //some codes for success. . . 

             },
});



$("#selection_filter").on('change',function(){

    var filter = $("#selection_filter").val();

    $("#keyword").attr("data-selection",filter);
});
```

This is the code for the events.

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; align: left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <h5>SEARCH ITEM</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 15%">
                    <label>Choose search filter: </label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <select id="selection_filter">
                        <option value="code">ITEM CODE</option>
                        <option value="itemname">ITEM NAME</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" style="width: 80%" data-selection="code" /> <input type="button" value="SEARCH" id="search-btn" class="k-button" style="font-size: 12px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This is my code for accessing the controller (CodeIgniter)

```
public function searchItem(){

            $query = $this->input->post('query');
            $filter = $this->input->post('data_filter');

            if($filter == "code"){
                $querySearch = "SELECT item_code,item_name from items WHERE item_code LIKE '%".$query."%' GROUP BY item_code";
            }else{
                $querySearch = "SELECT item_code,item_name from items WHERE item_name LIKE '%".$query."%' GROUP BY item_code";
            }

            $resultSearch = $this->db->query($querySearch);
            $count = $resultSearch->num_rows();

            echo json_encode($resultSearch->result_array());
            //echo json_encode($querySearch);

        }
```

What I want to get is:

In my ajax. There is a data that contains the value of keyword and data filter. Now What I need to do is get the data_filter value and pass it to the controller.

Comment: Can you post a sample reposnse json you are getting.?

Comment: {"item_code":"162103","item_name":" Sun00-INCOGNITO\r"}

Comment: You don't need to modify the title when the question is solved. I updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the response inside your ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: query_url,
            data:{query: $("#keyword").val(), data_filter: $("#keyword").attr("data-selection")},
            dataType:'json',
            async: false,
            success:function(res){
                 console.log(res.item_code);//Will give you the item code
                 console.log(res.item_name);//Will give you the item name
         },
});
```

Comment: Ok sir, but what I want is the data_filter value from the ajax data. I need to pass the ajax data to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it just an error in my syntax. Thanks for the response guys.